# standalone temperature logger for linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

please recommend me a temperature logger.

Requirements:

- Log temperature in every minute OR log hourly minimum,maximum in every hour
- Centigrades preferred to e.g. Fahrenheit
- It requires intervention only monthly or even less frequently, so for instance:

  - Can operate without a computer or external power source attached for at least a month (and can tell if it's due to replace/charge the battery in the next month, removable battery would be preferred)
  - Has sufficient storage (or SD card capability) for at least one month worth of data
- Supported by linux, preferably ubuntu
- CSV time,temperature output would be preferred to any other more complex output file formats
- USB communication is preferred to bluetooth. Bluetooth is preferred to RS232

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I ordered a EasyLog EL-SIE-1+ from Lascar Electronics and all the features worked with Linux (Tested on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS).

- Product Page = https://www.lascarelectronics.com/easylog-el-sie-1plus
- Datasheet =
  https://www.lascarelectronics.com/media/8411/easylog-data-logger-el-sie-1plus-iss4_11-22.pdf

All configuration and data extraction is done through your web browser connecting locally to the device via an included USB cable.  No special software, internet connection, or registration is required.  After plugging the device into your computer, navigate to http://EasyLog.local in your web browser to configure the device or download stored data.  You can download a raw CSV of your data or view a pretty graph from the web UI.

The device does have more thermal inertia than I'd like.  I did an experiment where I put it in my freezer (3F) and let it warm up in the ambient air of my house (77F)

- It took 8 minutes to go from 3F to 50F (77 ambient)
- It took 16 minutes to go from 3F to 60F (77 ambient)
- It took 27 minutes to go from 3F to 70F (77 ambient)
- It took 68 minutes to go from 3F to 77F (77 ambient)

Also, my device heated up significantly when plugged in via USB, displaying a temperature of 86F when the ambient temperature was 77F.  It will cool back down to ambient when unplugged but may take a while.

Despite the above quirks, I'd recommend this logger if your measured temperatures aren't changing rapidly.